# How to downgrade Java on El Capitan

Tags: java, macos

How do you downgrade Java version on MacOSX El Capitan? Right now when I run java -version I get:

> java version "9.0.1" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)

I need to have it say:

> java version "1.8.0_25" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)

So I can run a specific npm java based package.

I tried following [instructions](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_uninstall_java.xml) on Java website for uninstall/re-install with no luck. They suggest to run these 3 commands:

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin 
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefPane 
sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Application\ Support/Java
```

Doing this seems to do nothing. When I run `java -version` I still get the same result.

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lckoSmk534M) But I cannot find the JavaAppletPlugin.plugin referenced in video.

What am I doing wrong? How do you change Java version on El Capitan Mac OS?

Comment: try running a "which java" command from your prompt to see where Java is installed

Comment: it's in `/usr/bin`

Comment: don't try to delete it from there.  this link has some alternative suggestions as to where to remove your installation (sudo rm -fr /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/) from...  https://gist.github.com/schnell18/bcb9833f725be22f6acd01f94b486392 but the SDKMAN suggestion below might be a better option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at SDKMAN - http://sdkman.io/

You install it, then do `sdk list java`

```
sdk list java

================================================================================
Available Java Versions
================================================================================
     9.0.1-zulu
     9.0.1-oracle
     9.0.0-zulu
     8u152-zulu
     8u151-oracle
     8u144-zulu
 > + 8u141-oracle
     8u131-zulu
     7u141-zulu
     6u65-apple
```

You can install any or all of these, and select whichever one you want to use and set a default, as well:

See the docs here:

http://sdkman.io/usage.html